# Problem upgrading to 14.04 from 13.10. Screen turns on and off

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I am in the cleaning up part of the process of upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04.

The installer indicated me in a window to close open apps, after I did that window was gone, no OK button to click. The system is now for more than 12 hours switching between monitor on and off. It does not look like it is advancing with the install.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have GRUB installed? Restore then the old version 13.10 and open only a terminal and enter the follow command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Otherwise, shut down the pc by yourself and put it back on, look what it does then?

To install grub, enter the following in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && sudo boot-repair
```

Comment: I have GNU Grub. PC restarted OK. Ubuntu 14.04 is installed. It appears to me that clean up did not finish. How do I restore to 13.1?

Comment: Why would you get back to 13.10 if you have 14.04 now?

Comment: Do I need to complete cleaning? I thought maybe I needed to go back to complete cleaning.

Comment: No, you don't. :)